# String cannot be converted to String[] while making an object

Tags: java

I've looked through multiple threads but still can't understand what I'm doing wrongly. Honest help is appreciated.

In my codes, i'm trying to create a Card deck and initialise the values to every one of the array, 52 slots. However, when trying to do so, i kept getting the error String cannot be converted to String[].

What am i doing wrongly?

```
public class Card {
static String[] rank = {"2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
    static String[] suit = {"Spades","Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"};
    static Card[] deck = new Card[52];

    public Card(String[] rank, String[] suit)
    {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here


    for(int x = 0; x<deck.length; x++)
    {
        Card cards = new Card(rank[x%13], suit[x/13]);

    }
```

Comment: `new Card(rank[x%13], suit[x/13])` You're giving `String` objects to the constructor while its expecting `String[]` objects

Comment: The compiler also likely warns you that you are using the `this` qualifier (`this.rank` and `this.suit`) to access static fields.

Comment: `rank[x%13]` as a element of String array is a `String` while the `constructor` of Card accept a `String[]` parameter

Comment: Oh, so i should change my constructor to String right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new Card(rank[x%13], suit[x/13])` You're giving `String` objects to the constructor while its expecting `String[]` objects

The following might be a solution in your case.

```
String rank, suit;    
static String[] ranks = {"2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
static String[] suits = {"Spades","Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"};
static Card[] deck = new Card[52];

public Card(String rank, String suit)
{
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are confusing the arrays of possible ranks and suits for *all cards* and the concrete suit and rank of *one card*. My suggestion is to use plural vs singular to clearly differentiate both; and to change your constructor:

```
public class Card {
static String[] ranks = {"2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
    static String[] suits = {"Spades","Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"};
    static Card[] deck = new Card[52];

    private String rank;
    private String suit;

    public Card(String rank, String suit)
    {
        this.rank = rank; // stores variable 'rank' in attribute 'rank'
        this.suit = suit; // same for 'suit'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is taking `String array` instead of just `String` representing specific rank or color, moreover in constructor you're trying to assign to static array.

I think you don't want that, rename static members to some other name (such as `static String ranks_available[] = {...}`, etc.),  create non-static members representing rank and color of specific Card:

```
String rank;
String color;
```

And in your constructor take parameters rank and color as individual Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your Card constructor expect to be called with two array of string as parameter : `String[] rank, String[] suit`

When you do your loop :

```
for(int x = 0; x<deck.length; x++)
{
    Card cards = new Card(rank[x%13], suit[x/13]);

}
```

`rank[x%13]` is actually give you a `String`. For exemple when `x = 13` then `rank[13%13] = rank[0] = "2"`

`"2"` because the index 0 of your array of string `rank` is equivalent to that string :

```
static String[] ranks = {"2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
```

Given that you constructor expect an Array of `String`, the compilator warn you that a `String` is not the type of parameter expected.